# Android Studio keeps generating Eclipse-like files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, aidl

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and I have noticed that for one of my projects (only this one) it generates `.project` files and a `bin` directory like Eclipse does (I suppose).

The project was created in AS 3.0.1 and it was not migrated from Eclipse or anything like this. It also doesn't use any fancy Gradle plugins or dependencies - just the generated ones (AppCompat + Kotlin).

Do you have any idea why it does so?

[image: project file structure]

Also, when I was trying to prepare a minimal project for reproduction, I noticed that the problem disappears just by copy-pasting the whole project directory so there's probably no point in sharing it with you.

Using two project copies (let's call them `original` and `copy`) I was able to find out that when I close Android Studio and clean both copies using `git clean -xfd`

- `copy` has no issues when opened - no Eclipse-like files
- `original` still has the issue when opened (files get generated)
- `diff -r` before opening them (so just after `git clean`) gives only this:

  > Binary files ../PWTA_Proj2/.git/index and ./.git/index differ
- both of them make Android Studio show an error like this when opened:

  > Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: PWTA_Proj2. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

Despite of the error I can build the project normally. Also I don't have any non-Gradle modules - the project is very simple and generated by AS. The only less common thing is that the project contains a few AIDL files.

***Edit #1: Gradle files:***

top-level `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

top-level `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app'
```

`app` module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        final appId = "com.azabost.pwta.proj2"
        applicationId appId
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders.tspProcessName = appId + ".tsp"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your build.gradle files? I suspect the eclipse plugin is activated

Comment: @StavSaad Sure, please check the edited question.

Comment: In my case this problem was not with Android Studio, but with VSCode and its java extension. This issue seems related https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/618.